# Tips for a scalable web app architecture

Tags: python, web-applications, architecture

Are there any rules of thumb or any general tips for designing a scalable, high performance web app? Especially on the architecture. For example, how to separate out the front-end from the back-end (if at all)? My main interest is in Python, but any general advice will definitely help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general advice: http://highscalability.com/

Please be more specific about your requirnments.

Answer (score 0):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a great python-based web framework I would recommend to anyone!